# main.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `reciprocal'

Tags: c, makefile

This is a sample program i was trying to compile this below c program to know about the 
make file.

### main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "reciprocal.h"
int main(int argc,char **argv){
 int i;
 i=atoi(argv[1]);
 printf("The Reciprocal of %d is %f\n ",i,reciprocal(i));
 return 0;
}
```

### reciprocal.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include "reciprocal.h"
double reciprocal(int i){
assert(i!=0);
return 1.0/i;
}
```

### reciprocal.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C"{
#endif
extern double reciprocal(int i);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}   
#endif
```

### makefile

```
CFLAGS:=-o2
reciprocal: reciprocal.o main.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal.o main.o
main.o: main.c reciprocal.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -I ../include 
reciprocal.o: reciprocal.c reciprocal.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c reciprocal.c -I ../include 
clean: 
        rm -f *.o reciprocal
```

when compiled as below it throws an error.

% make

> gcc -o2 -c reciprocal.c -I ../include  gcc -o2 -c main.c -I ../include
>   gcc -o2 -o reciprocal.o main.o main.o: In function `main':
>   main.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to`reciprocal' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [reciprocal] Error 1

Please help me understand what is the reason for this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your makefile:

```
reciprocal: reciprocal.o main.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal reciprocal.o main.o
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively:

```
reciprocal: reciprocal.o main.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Thanks That error is fixed. But still i'm getting an error as "gcc: reciprocal.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [reciprocal] Error 1"

Comment: @Angus Not sure. Is `reciprocal.o` available to gcc ?

Comment: yes cnicutar. Its available as gcc $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal reciprocal.o main.o

Answer (score 4):

You have an insidious typo:

```
CFLAGS:=-o2
```

That should have been `-O2` with a capital `O`, this way you redirect the output of every compilation to the file `2`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for correclty pointing out the mistake i have committed.